# React Native Router Flux Tab Navigation does not show Tab Icon for one specific component

Tags: android, react-native, tabs, flux, vector-icons

I've got a problem with react native router flux navigation. I want to display an icon for my tabs with react-native-vector-icons but for the component {ScreenOverview} it doesn't show the icon.

Code:

```
const Scenes = Actions.create(
<Router>
    <Scene key='root' hideNavBar>

        <Scene
            key='amount'
            component={ScreenAmountPlayer}
            title='AmountOfPlayer'
            initial
        />

        <Scene
            key='names'
            component={ScreenEnterPlayerNames}
            title='EnterNames'
            hideNavBar
        />

        <Scene
            key='playScreen'
            hideNavBar
            tabs={true}
        >

            <Scene
                key='Play!'
                component={PlayScreen}
                icon={TabIcon}
                iconName={'play-circle-o'}
                hideNavBar
            />

            <Scene
                key='Overview'
                iconName={'list-ul'}
                icon={TabIcon}
                component={ScreenOverview}
                hideNavBar
            />

        </Scene>

    </Scene>
</Router>
)
```

With this code it looks like that:
[image]

When I change the second scene to:

```
<Scene
    key='Overview'
    iconName={'list-ul'}
    icon={TabIcon}
    component={PlayScreen}
    hideNavBar
/>
```

It looks like that: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I simply wrapped around my scenes another scene and it worked

```
        <Scene
            key='playScreen'
            hideNavBar
            tabs={true}
        >
            <Scene key='PlayWrapper' icon={TabIcon} iconName={'play-circle-o'} hideNavBar tabBarLabel='Play!'>
                <Scene
                    key='Play!'
                    component={PlayScreen}
                    hideNavBar
                />
            </Scene>

            <Scene key='OverviewWrapper' iconName={'list-ul'} icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar tabBarLabel='Overview'>
                <Scene
                    key='Overview'
                    component={ScreenOverview}
                    hideNavBar
                />
            </Scene>
        </Scene>
```